Correct usage of "this" in assemblyscript
I'm working on an AssemblyScript application. The way the code is structured requires passing an instance of a class in the constructor of another class. For example:
class Something {

  constructor(private context: MyContext) { }

  testMethod(): void {
    //Some logic which uses variables and methods from context class  
    let a: this.context.getSomething();
  }
}

class MyContext {
  
  //Is below a correct usage of 'this'?
  somethingObj: Something = new Something(this);

  myMethod(): void {
    //Some logic which uses somethingObj
    this.somethingObj.testMethod()
  }
  
}

I'm able to build and run the code successfully. But, is the above field somethingObj in MyContext class correctly using 'this' keyword? Could this somehow lead to some runtime errors around out of bounds memory access?

Answer:

I'm able to build and run the code successfully.

Good.  This shows your code is working.

_But, is the above field somethingObj in MyContext class correctly using 'this' keyword?

Yes, it is using it correctly.

Could this somehow lead to some runtime errors around out of bounds memory access?

No.  You are not performing any unsafe operations that would access memory out of bounds.  If such an error did occur with this code, that would be an indication of a compiler bug and should be reported as an issue on the AssemblyScript GitHub repository.
Explanation:
this refers to the instance of the current class.  In your example, when MyContext is constructed, the somethingObj field is instantiated with a default value.  You're creating that value by constructing another object Something, and passing the current instance of MyContext (using this) as a parameter to the constructor.
Your code is fine.

Also, for future reference, since you've no actual problem to solve, your question could be considered off-topic here.  CodeReview.SE would be more appropriate, IMHO.
